# Notificaciones para navegadores mobiles javascript

Tags: javascript, notificaciones

Buenas tardes quisiera saber si existe una funcion javascript o jquery (lo mismo pero mas simplificado) para poder enviar notificaciones en un navegador movil.

por ejemplo la url siguiente:
https://ajpalacios.github.io/notifications-html5/
es un demo de notificaciones; en pc (chrome) va bien, pero lo testie en chrome para celular (android) y di click en el boton y nada, me aparecio una alerta para darle permisos de notificaciones y le di aceptar pero nada. por lo que veo el codigo de https://ajpalacios.github.io/notifications-html5/ sirve solo para navegadores de escritorio y no para moviles.

Alguien sabra de alguna libreria o funcion para logran las notificaciones tanto en movil como en pc ?

Comment: Para recomendaciones de software o librerías mejor hacer la pregunta en [reddit](https://www.reddit.com), [quora](https://es.quora.com) o incluso [yahoo respuestas](https://es.answers.yahoo.com). Aquí en [es.so] las preguntas deben ser sobre problemas específicos y no para pedir recomendaciones. Te invito a leer [ask] y a dar una lectura al [help/dont-ask]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, aunque poco util pero bueno, seguire esperando a alguien que me ayude y entienda el contexto de la pregunta sin mucha formalidad.

OJO: no estoy pidiendo recomendaciones de software, estoy preguntando el codigo javascript. Buen dia

Answer (score 0):

Echale un ojo a esta libreria

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>   
    
    
    toastr["info"]("Tienes  cambios en sus tareas para asignar<br /><br />", "Planificador")
```

Comment: eso sirve para notificaciones dentro de la web, pero para notificaciones externas, por ejemplo en chrome de pc salen alertas en window y en telefono sale notificaciones push